# QR Code scan doesn't work with Barcode Scanner

Tags: android, zxing, qr-code, barcode-scanner, scanning

I'm developing an android application for a tablet (model SynchroDigital INOSOP10-4.0 RES) and I'd like to use the ZXing library to scan a QRcode containing a string. It does launch the scanner when I need it but I can't scan anything.

Actually it doesn't even work if I use directly the Barcode Scanner application, the yellow dots appear but nothing happens, no matter the luminosity, the distance or the complexity of the QR Code (tried with a huge QR Code just containing the letter "A"), it just won't work.

Yet it works perfectly with another code scanner, the one from the pic2shop app !

The tablet's webcam is 1,3MP and doesn't have autofocus.

Does the issue come from the webcam ? Are there any others libraries I can easily implement instead of the ZXing one ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post an example image? Something may not be valid about it.

Comment: @SeanOwen : a QR code example ? I tried with different codes from different sources and it never worked (although it always worked with the Barcode Scanner app on my Galaxy S). I can't scan this one for instance : [link](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=350x350&chld=L&choe=Shift_JIS&chl=a)

Comment: @Shaiful I don't think my code matters here, because that's the Barcode Scanner application that doesn't work. If you want to know, I just call the scanner with an integrator :

`IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
integrator.initiateScan();`

Comment: Is the barcode flipped over? These aren't valid; maybe some app allows it. QR codes are so easy to scan that it can't be an app issue. Post an example image of a QR code you can't scan.

Comment: Ok I get it, I forgot to mention that the camera is frontal, so the code is flipped over, that's why it didn't work. I "mirrored" it with paint and it works well. Thanks for putting me on the right track. Is it possible to configure the tablet so I can get a mirrored image with the frontal webcam and be able to scan codes ? I hope I'm clear, my english is pretty average.

Comment: It seems that there is a feature in the settings that would reverse the image, according to your posts I just read on various forums, but there isn't such a thing in the settings of the app I installed (4.2 version, the latest one). I just can choose which kind of codes I want to scan, what I want to do when the code is scanned and some other general settings. How can I enable this feature ?

Answer (score 0):

use below code, it will work for QR scanning, but it wouldn't work for barcode scan -

```
Intent objIntent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"); 
objIntent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE"); 
startActivityForResult(objIntent, 0);
```

or use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(shopping.this, CaptureActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```